# Установка MSSQL сервера, создание пользователей, и удалённое управление

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
есть компьютер, на который надо установить ms sql server (только сервер)  и к нему будут подключаться приложения с сети.
Когда я устанавливаю sql сервер то по умолчанию доступ к базам имеет только локальный компьютер, т.е. мне надо создать пользователя при использ ms sql аутентификации и "открыть ворота во внешний мир", что б его видели
здесь нашёл как это всё делать...
h**ttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XH-qVhxwQs&feature=g-all-fbc&context=G2d5bfd2FAAAAAAAAOAA**
всё работает, как и говорят.....
у меня на компе всё работает 
а на "том" компьютере я хочу установить только сервер....ну и managment studio. что б создать пользователя, полные права дать...и в дальнейшем управлять с моего компа....а тот managm stud  можно вообщем даже и удалить....
но получается что для установки нужна ещё и visual studio а если установить ms sql server 2012 (ну это чисто для извращения)...то ещё и sp1 нужен..
Вообщем сильно долго говорю....
студию там устанавливать не хочу..и др.дополнения
это не такой уж громадный проект
можно ли установить только сервер.....ну и например прогу devart (но в ней я не нашёл как в managment studio, как создать пользователя и т.д.) и запустить скрипт, что б создал пользователя.....
а в дальнейшем работать с сервером удалённо....
```

Comment: Что это за каша? У вас нет времени даже на то, чтобы нормально сформулировать свой вопрос?

Comment: Если чтото не устраивает, предлагаю закрыть страницу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вверху диалогов в Management Studio есть кнопочка "Скрипт". Если её нажать, Management Studio сгенерирует скрипт, выполняющий ту же сервисную операцию, которая настраивается текущим диалогом.

Потом этот скрипт можно выполнить на другой машине.